# Configure Apache to run website off of port-enabled IP address

Tags: apache, digital-ocean

To be perfectly honest, I'm not even sure if this is doable...

I've configured my vhosts file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled which you can see here:

```
<VirtualHost 159.203.171.140:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName 159.203.171.140:8080
    DocumentRoot "/home/wiki/public_html"

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

    <Directory "/home/wiki/public_html">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wiki_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wiki_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

for a digitalocean droplet given at the IP listed in the above hosts file. This droplet has absolutely nothing on it except for the wiki user in /home/ plus the required php, mysql/mariadb, apache stuff.

What I want to be able to do is to go to 159.203.171.140:8080 and see my site without having to purchase a useless domain name.

I'd really appreciate some help with this one.

Comment: And exactly how is this not working?

Comment: When I go to 159.203.171.140:8080 it does not work. Apache has been restarted several times and I'm unable to connect to that port.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like a portscan of your ip to make sure that 8080 is open to the outside world? check the firewall to see if 8080's allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one website on the droplet, then you don't need to set up a virtual host.  You can use the 000-default.conf, no need for `a2ensite`.

You do not need the `ServerName`, which won't work with the IP as a name, you also don't need the IP address in the `VirtualHost` directive.

So, instead of this:

```
<VirtualHost 159.203.171.140:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName 159.203.171.140:8080
    DocumentRoot "/home/wiki/public_html"
    ...
```

You can use this in your 000-default.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
     DocumentRoot "/home/wiki/public_html"
     ...
```

The rest of the directive stays as you have it.

Also, one note, if you are using port 8080, then you need go to `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and set the Listen to 8080 (restart Apache after doing this).